# stage.mouseLock on AIR - Error #1056

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm having a problem setting the `stage.mouseLock` property on **AIR** (3.2-3.4)

Compiling the following class in a **FlashPlayer** (11.2-11.4) Project works fine:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main() 
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        }

        private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            stage.mouseLock = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile the same class targeting AIR instead of FlashPlayer, the following error occurs:

`Error #1056: Cannot create property mouseLock on flash.display.Stage.`

I'm using `AIR SDK Version: 3.4.0.2710` and FlashDevelop 4.1.0 as my IDE.

**EDIT**:
Even after a clean install of FlashDevelop, downloading Flex SDK, AIR SDK, FlashPlayerDebugger from scratch, the problem persists.

**EDIT 2**:
Thank you, TheDarkIn1978.
After adding the `-swf-version=17` AND editing the `application.xml` to use the correct version (3.4) manually, it worked...
I'll try to find out if it is a bug in the latest FlashDevelop or AIR SDK (probably is in the FD)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct so i think you need to check to see if FlashDevelop is indeed targeting at least *AIR SDK 3.2*.

First, comment out the offending code and trace the runtime version in your constructor:

```
trace("AIR SDK Version: ", NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion);
```

This should output at least:

> *AIR SDK Version:  3.2.x.xxxx*

If not, you should check which Flex SDK (with AIR) FlashDevelop is targeting:

***Tools > Program Settings > AS3Context > Language > Installed Flex SDKs***

If you're unsure which version you have or you are targeting a version earlier than AIR SDK 3.2, you can download the latest AIR SDK (pre-merged with Flex SDK) from Adobe's Gaming site ([Download the Adobe® AIR® SDK](http://gaming.adobe.com/getstarted/)), save it to disk and link its location to FlashDevelop.

[image]

**[EDIT]**

---

One last thing I forgot to mention:  Make sure your project platform target is set to at least AIR 3.2 and that your project AIR SDK target settings aren't overriding your global AIR SDK target settings.

***Project > Properties***

[image]

[image]

**[EDIT 2]**

---

Try manually overriding the target swf version and assign it to version 17.

***Project > Properties > Compiler Options > Advanced > Additional Compiler Options***

Add the following to the compiler options array:

> -swf-version=17

[image]

Comment: As stated above, my AIR SDK is 3.4 (`AIR SDK Version:  3.4.0.2710`), still, I don't know what is happening...

Comment: i've had some bizarre errors once before from manually merged the Flex 4.6 SDK with a recent AIR SDK incorrectly.  perhaps you've done the same?  maybe try downloading the pre-merged AIR SDK from Adobe's site to see if that fixes the error for you.  are you running FlashDevelop 4.0.4 RTM?

Comment: I did a fresh install of my FlashDevelop (4.1.0). It downloaded the AIR SDK, Flex SDK, FlashPlayerDebugger from scratch... I've started a new (clean) project, with just this test class. Even after these, the problem persists.

Comment: crazy!  your code works fine for me.  have you checked the application.xml to make sure it's using the correct application namespace?  it should be `<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4">`

Comment: Nice spot... The value were wrong (was 3.1), but even after changing that (to 3.4), it doesn't make it work either... I'm freaking out!

Comment: edited my answer again.  you may have to manually override the swf version which the compiler is suppose to target, even though the player/debugger is running in AIR 3.4, the compiler might be trying to compile in an earlier version.  swf-version 17 is for AIR 3.4.

Comment: Bingo! There must be some bug in the SDK or in the FlashDevelop in compiling time that isn't doing the job right... After adding the swf-version tag it worked... Thanks!!

Comment: great!  i'm glad it's solved.  unfortunately, the compiler arguments are project specific, so you'll have to add it for each new project until the problem is solved.  i think the error is with the SDKs that are downloaded and installed by FlashDevelop.  I believe that if you download the SDK from Adobe and point FlashDevelop to use that one instead then everything should work.  Regardless, it's nice to finally know what the problem was. :)

Comment: An, another thing that MUST be noted... Adding the swf-version tag without changing the `application.xml` will result in a compiling failure...